# Changing Grafana port

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I currently have InfluxDB feeding dashboards in Grafana.  I will eventually be deploying this stack on a server.

However, the default port for Grafana is 80.  I must change this port, but I don't know how.  Can anyone help out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Not only change in `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` you have to change in 
`/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini` and `/usr/share/grafana/conf/sample.ini` files. Just search `3000` port(which is default port for grafana) in these three files and replace it with your preferred port.

Comment: this works, but why do i need to change sample.ini too?

Comment: You don't. It is not used.

Answer (score 20):

Here's the easiest way I found.

```
docker run -d \
-p 2345:2345 \
--name grafana \
-e "GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT=2345" \
grafana/grafana
```

See the documentation here.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker/#configuration

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for so long to get this fixed. You made my day!

Answer (score 7):

Since Grafana 2.0:

> Grafana now ships with its **own backend server**

You can edit /etc/grafana/grafana.ini (usual location) and change the running port:

```
[server]
http_port=1234
```

Source:
http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/

Comment: The Arch grafana package has it's ini located at `/etc/grafana.ini`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux, you can change the default port by changing the port from `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`. There is no separate `custom.ini` for Linux. For Windows, MacOS or any other platform, check the [official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/).

For opening `grafana.ini`, you would need `sudo` privileges. For changing the port please follow the steps below.

1. Execute `sudo gedit /etc/grafana/grafana.ini` in a new Terminal window.
2. Search for `3000` in the `.ini. file and you will find a line similar to the one shown below.

```
# The http port  to use
;http_port = 3000
```

3. Remove the semicolon (`;`) and change the port to the port that you wish to run the grafana server on.
4. Save the file and close gedit.
5. You will need to restart the Grafana server for the changes to take place. Run `sudo systemctl restart grafana-server`.

The grafana server should be started on the port that you provided. Please note that you will have to write `systemctl` or `service` depending upon your init system. To determine your init system, run `ps --no-headers -o comm 1`.

[Source](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/)

Answer (score 2):

For those using Docker:

Create a `grafana.ini`:

```
   [server]
   http_port = 1234
```

Update your Dockerfile:

```
    FROM grafana/grafana

    EXPOSE 1234

    ADD grafana.ini /etc/grafana
```

Build and run the container:

```
    docker build grafana

    docker run \
    -d \
    -p 1234:1234 \
    --name grafana \
    grafana/grafana
```

The `EXPOSE` is technically optional but is [good practice for documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

Comment: Thanks. Works for me

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, I grab the setup file form here
https://grafana.com/grafana/download?platform=linux

Then install it!

You only need to change this one `/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini`:

Replace:

```
http_port = 3000
```

With

```
http_port = YourPortYouWant
```

Then restart your app:

```
sudo service grafana-server stop
sudo service grafana-server start
```

To verify you should run:

```
sudo service grafana-server status
```

Then you can see the app lives in your desired port:
[image]

Open up `localhost:yourport` to see the result.

I think the document from Grafana should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

On windows,

1. Change port from 3000 to 3001 in "C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\conf\defaults.ini"
2. Restart Grafana service from windows services

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 and Grafana v7.1.1, the following steps made the Grafana to be served in different port:

1. Navigate to the Grafana "conf" folder location like "C:\Program Files\GrafanaLabs\grafana\conf"
2. Copy the file "sample.ini" in the same location
3. Rename the copied sample.ini to "custom.ini"
4. Edit the "custom.ini" by opening in any editor.The editor must be running as Administrator.
5. Uncomment the ";http_port = 3000" line by removing the semicolon(;). Note: Semicolon(;) is used to comment out lines in .ini files
6. Change the port "3000" to whatever port is required. Make sure the new port should be admin rights. I changed to port "3001".
7. Save the file.
8. Restart the Windows machine.

The Grafana url is now hosted in "http://localhost:3001/?orgId=1"

Answer (score 0):

I know its old thread but for me in Mac i had to make changes at 2 places.

I installed through Brew

/usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini

/usr/local/Cellar/grafana/8.1.5/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini

Answer (score -1):

Grafana just runs behind a standard web server, like apache. If you are using apache, just update your virtual hosts file to use whatever port you want, and restart apache. Grafana will then be on the new port.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove (;), like this:

http_port = 3900