# Grafana dashboard uploading in my external website

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grafana

I am trying to embed Grafana live dashboard in my own external website, which is running in my google cloud, by using iFrame. Since Grafana is executed in my local page only (http://localhost:3000/), I am not able to upload my dashboard in my webpage. I have no idea how to make it online so I can embed it online. Does anyone know how to connect my local Grafana dashboard to online?

I already modified custom.ini to allow embedding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your web browser and go to http://localhost:3000/.

   The default HTTP port that Grafana listens to is 3000 unless you have
   configured a different port.
2. On the sign-in page, enter admin for the username and password.
3. Click Sign in.
   If successful, you will see a prompt to change the password.
4. Click OK on the prompt and change your password.

Steps to create a dashboard:

1. Click the New dashboard item under the Dashboards icon in the side menu.
2. On the dashboard, click Add an empty panel.
3. In the New dashboard/Edit panel view, go to the Query tab.
4. Configure your query by selecting -- Grafana -- from the data source selector.This generates the Random Walk dashboard.
5. Click the Save icon in the top right corner of your screen to save the dashboard.
6. Add a descriptive name, and then click Save.

Also check this link on  [Embedding Grafana dashboard in a website](https://www.itpanther.com/embedding-grafana-in-iframe/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. but, what is the difference of chaning the port?

Comment: Changing port numbers is more secure, than leaving them as they are. Since Grafana doesn't come with TLS by default, we'll use Caddy to obtain a certificate for Grafana by tunnelling out port 80 and 443 instead of the plaintext HTTP port 3000. Your Grafana dashboard may be deployed inside Kubernetes, or as a Docker container.Also refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303978/changing-grafana-port).